# C# Winforms DataGridView: manipulating data by user input AND programmatically leads to first chance error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, binding

I have an input enabled DataGridView bound to a BindingSource which has a SortableBindingList as DataSource.

There is no direct connection to the database. The list is read once from the database beforehand. After the user is done with editing he can choose either to save the changed data to the database or not.

The list has 2 fields:

- "Type" (enum)
- "Path" (string)

As I want to use a ComboBox for the user to select the "Type" I add an additional column "TypeCbx" which is bound to the enum values. Initially, all "Type" values from the list are copied to the column "TypeCbx" and for changes, the value of "TypeCbx" is copied back to "Type" in the event ...CellEndEdit().

Furthermore, I have 2 button columns included:

- "Browse" button: opens a FolderDialog for the user in order to adjust the actual row and set the column "Path" and (if it is a new row/entry) a default value to "Type"
- "Remove" button: removes the row/entry from the DGV

This worked as long as I used an unbound DataTable in which I had the following code for the button "Browse":

```
private void dgvPaths_OpenFolderClick(DataGridView sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    string newSelectedPath = Helper.FileBrowserDialog("Select folder", LastSelectedPath);
    if (newSelectedPath != null) {
        LastSelectedPath = Helper.CleanPath(newSelectedPath);

        if (dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) {
            // --- variante old: unbound datatable ----------------------------------------
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgvPaths.Rows[0].Clone();
            row.Cells[dgvPaths.Columns["Path"].Index].Value = LastSelectedPath;
            row.Cells[dgvPaths.Columns["Type"].Index].Value = LibraryPathType.Movies;
            row.Cells[dgvPaths.Columns["TypeCbx"].Index].Value = LibraryPathType.Movies;
            row.Cells[dgvPaths.Columns["TypeCbx"].Index].ReadOnly = false;
            dgvPaths.Rows.Add(row);
            dgvPaths_CellValueChanged(sender, e);
        } else if (dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Path"].Value == null || LastSelectedPath != dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Path"].Value.ToString()) {
            dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Path"].Value = LastSelectedPath;
            dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TypeCbx"].ReadOnly = false;
            dgvPaths_CellValueChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, with the bound DataSource, the line `dgvPaths.Rows.Add(row);` no longer works. So I adjusted the code as follows:

```
            // --- variante new 1: bound list, working on dgv -----------------------------
            dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Path"].Value = LastSelectedPath;
            dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Type"].Value = LibraryPathType.Movies;
            dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TypeCbx"].Value = LibraryPathType.Movies;
            dgvPaths.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TypeCbx"].ReadOnly = false;
            dgvPaths_CellValueChanged(sender, e);
```

**Issue 1:**
Now, the data is written into the row of the DataGridView but the DataGridView does not interpret it as an input and therefore it is not really added - it still is a "new Row" waiting for input. I need to manually go into the Path Column of the row and press a key in order that the DataGridView accepts it as a valid entry and shows a new "new Row" line.

**=> How can I inform the DataGridView that programmatically entered data should be handled like a user input?**

**Issue 2:**
Furthermore, when I manually enter an entry in the DataGridView and click in the "Path" column between the added line and the new "new Row" line, a first chance exception is thrown.

**=> What is the reason for the first chance exception?**

Then I've read that you should not manipulate the DataGridView but instead the BindingSouce or BindingSource.DataSource, which I tried with by changing the code to this:

```
            // --- variante new 2: bound list, working on datasource ----------------------
            Library.Current.AddDirtyPath(LibraryPathType.Movies, LastSelectedPath);
```

**Issue 3:**
Hereby, I also get a first chance exception when this entry is added to the source list.

**=> What is the reason for the first chance exception?**

What is the correct approach here?

**=> Do I need to manipulate the rows of the DataGridView or the entries of the BindingSource or the entries of the BindingSource.DataSource?**

**Issue 4:**
The bound DataGridView threw another exception when loading the DataSource and there is no enum value for "0" (I guess for the "new Row" line). Therefore, I needed to add a dummy enum value which is set to "0" to my enum value list which I need to skip again for the actual ComboBox selection values. It works but it messes up the code.

**=> Is it possible to avoid this dummy value, at all?**

--- U P D A T E ---

After reading Caius recommendation, I have decided to update this question as I was able to follow the SBL approach and reduce the issues.

The correct approach here is to use a main "storage" SBL for all working data (which is initially filled by reading the DB) and create a filtered SBL out of it which is used as DS for the DGV where the user can work on and use sort and filter methods. By adding/updating/removing data, you have to ensure that all adjustments stay synchronous in the "storage" SBL. Then, when you want to update the DB, you use the 'storage' SBL.

Thereby only 1 issue is left: if you want to add a new line with a button column function inside the DGV itself. It fails as the state of the actual new line is changed while you are calling the add function from inside the DGV. There are 2 ways to "fix" this:

a) You need to completely(!) `Clear()` the SBL that is used as DS for the DGV and add the new line afterwards (according with all other existing ones from the "storage" list) back to this SBL. Thereby the state of the new line is also changed but as it is completely removed the state is also cleared. After this you need to `Refresh()` the DGV. Hereby, you will lose focus of the actual cell.

b) You use a hidden button outside of the DGV by `btnAdd.PerformClick()` which calls the add function in which you do not need to `Clear()` the SBL that is bound to the DGV. This seems strange but it works (whyever) and you keep the focus on the "new line" row (not on the added one).

All other functions like updating and removing an existing DGV line can be called by additional button columns within the DGV itself without issues.

The enum issue is not an issue as it is common to use a dummy zero value for empty entries. If I find out, how to get rid of the dummy value, I will update this question accordingly.

In order to fill the combobox column without a split between display and value columns you only need to ensure that the DataPropertyName of the combobox column is set like the DB column name.

--- U P D A T E: 2 ---

I have created a detailed video (tutorial) about my approach:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_afaNf7nz8

From 1:31:20 I show the difference between adding a new line by an external and an internal button and also the strange behaviour of using the method directly (=> error) or triggering an external button which uses the same method (=> no error).

Comment: Manipulate the data behind the grid and not fiddle with cell/rows etc. when you change data programmatically. Its normally a good habit to have a enum value with backing value 0 that has the meaning of none/unseleted etc. Besides that to many questions/details involved to actually answer all of that. Its a to broad design question.

Comment: Thanks - yea, I think the struggles are a result of correcting the user's input ("clean" the path value, check for non-existing paths and restoring the old path value on wrong inputs). But here, I have no idea how I should adopt the existing code as the entry should not be added or changed on wrong user inputs. Furthermore, I have the actual source (the BS and its SBL along with the methods to add/remove entries from the SBL) in a complete other singleton class and not in the form itself. Is there perhaps a helpful guide how to work with bound DGV and programmed adjustments of the user inputs?

Comment: When do you need those adjustments? While editing the grid and for example preventing closing the celleditor or leaving the cell. Or do you need it when changing rows or when sending data to a store? There is presumably no fitting guide as there are multiple layers where it can happen, when it can happen and why it can happen. To many variants.

Comment: I want to reverse wrong inputs before they are written to the SBL (or shown in the DGV). In unbound mode: for existing entries I use CellBeginEdit() to store the old valid DGV.ROW["Path"].Value), then I check the new value in CellEndEdit() and if it is wrong I replace the DGV.ROW.value with the valid old value or remove the DGV.ROW (if wrong data has been entered in a new row). I adopt the changed value(s) in CellValueChanged() to the DataTable (and do not need to update the DGV as the DGV already has the correct actual data). Now, I am stuck how to do the same with a bound DGV.

Comment: When I try "Variante 2 new" - the exception is thrown as there is an entry in the SBL with Path = null. When I remove all those "null" entries the new entry is added to the list but it seems that somehow the DGV adds a null entry again (with the "new Row" line, I guess) and then it throws the exception again after clicking between an existing row and the "new Row" - very strange behaviour.

Comment: @tar, Can you [edit] your question and clearly explain what is supposed to happen when the user interacts with the grid cells. We are aware that you have “certain” issues, however, it is unclear “what” the overall goal is. Currently your question is very broad and involves numerous issues. Please make it clear what you are trying to do and what is not working. You keep adding more details in the comments which is NOT going to help you. If a comment adds clarity to the question, then ADD it to the QUESTION. Do not add it as a comment. I will be glad to help if I knew what the goal was.

Comment: @JohnG I don't understand what is missing as I clearly explained what should happen and what instead happenes resp. is not working. I also do not understand that I seem to be the only person to have issues switching DGV processing from unbound to bound mode with the usage of buttons (especially with the ADD function within the "Browse" button within a new line), user input validation(s) and enums. Now, I have created a little DGV "testtool" this night to focus on each issue separately and if I am not able to fix those I will ask again for each issue separately.

Comment: You're having issues because you switched to bound mode and then carry on trying to add data to the grid. Don't. Add it to the datatable directly and the grid will update itself

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct approach here?

You have a datagridview

You bind its DataSource to a datatable

You have a datagridviewcombobox

You bind it's DataSource to a *completely different* datatable

You tell the combo which columns, from its own datatable, are to be used for display, value and which column in the table that the grid is bound to, shall be updated/used for deciding which value to Show

---

```
var gdt = new DataTable();
gdt.Columns.Add("FileType", typeof(FileType));//enum
gdt.Columns.Add("Path");

gdt.Rows.Add(FileType.Text, "c:\my.txt");

var fdt = new DataTable();
fdt.Columns.Add("Val", typeof(FileType));//enum
fdt.Columns.Add("Disp");

foreach(FileType t in Enum.GetValues<FileType>())
{
  fdt.Rows.Add(t, t.ToString());
}

//now wire it up
datagridviewWhatever.DataSource = gdt; //makes columns 

var c = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
c.DisplayMember = "Disp"; //name of column in fdt to use for show
c.ValueMember = "Val"; //name of column in fdt to use for value during lookup/set operations
c.DataPropertyName = "FileType"; //name of column in gdt that this combo shall show/set
c.DataSource = fdt; //set DataSource last (performance reasons)
```

Combo will now, for each row, get the value in gdt.FileType (eg FileType.Text), lookup the value in its own table fdt.Val, use the related value in fdt.Disp (eg "Text") to show in the list. If the user chooses a new list item (eg "Excel") it goes the other way, get the relevant Val (eg FileType.Excel) chosen and push it into gdt.FileType

I've never actually done it with enum typed values; can't see why it wouldn't work but if it gives trouble it might be simpler to switch to using ints instead of FileTypes - make all your typeof() calls typeof(int) and cast the FileType t to int in the foreach when adding it to the row collection.

---

Finally, when you're down with this as a concept I recommend throwing it all away and doing it using the visual designer - it will make a much better, nicer, easier to use job of it:

- add a DataSet type file to your project
- open it
- if there is a database somewhere backing all this, right click on the design surface and choose Add TableAdapter, enter the connection string, choose a query, that returns rows, put `SELECT * FROM MovieFiles WHERE ID = @id` or whatever, call it FillById/GetDataById, finish
- if there isn't a database backing all this just right click the surface, add a datatable called MovieFiles, right click it and add columns like FileType (set type to int in property grid), Path etc
- right click a blank space and add another datatable called FileTypes, put a string column called Disp and an int column called Val (sounding familiar?)
- save and switch to Forms designer. Open Data Sources tool panel (View menu.. other windows submenu)
- Drag the MovieFiles node out of data sources and into the form. A datagridview appears as well as a bunch of stuff in the bottom tray. The grid is already correctly binded to the DataSet that contains the MovieFiles table. You can see all the code VS is writing for you in the Forms.Designer. It looks a lot like the code I put manually above
- Edit the columns of the datagridview, change the file type column to be a combobox type, set the DataSource to the FileTypes table, DisplayMember to Disp, ValueMemberto Val. Check the DataPropertyName is still FileType in movies - this should also be familiar as it's the visual version of the code above)
- the only thing left to do is put some code in the constructor that fills the FileTypes table from the enum (or to be honest, just make a table in the DB called FileTypes, have an int and a string column, add a tableadapter, select them.. that way you don't have to recompile the whole program when you add a file type)

Why do I advocate using these visually designed datatables rather than code ones? Because they're so much nicer in every single way. They have logical methods and named properties for columns, they just work with LINQ and they behave like .net classes that are collections of POCOs not 2D arrays of `object` that are indexed by string and need casting to make them useful. DataTable are awful to work with in comparison. They wrap around basic DataTable and do expose them but follow a rule that if you've exposed it, you've probably gone wrong

```
//no; using .Tables puts you back in "world of pain"
var p = (string)datasetX.Tables["MovieTypes"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().First()["Path"];

//yes - using named property for MovieTypes is good, LINQ works, Path is a string property etc
var p = datasetX.MovieFiles.First().Path;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I found out that you do not need 2 columns for a (select & display) combobox conversion. You only need to set the DataPropertyName of the combobox column like the corresponding db table column name. Furthermore, you are using DataTables and no (Sortable)Binding(Source/List) which would bring me back to unbound mode as in the designer there is a) no "TableAdapter" anywhere and b) no option to connect to my SQLite DB without installing/setting up additional server stuff (e.g. ODBC) which would prevent that the whole app stays portable. Now, I use 3 dlls and am fine.

Comment: DataTable or BindingList, it doesn't matter - theyre both just a collection of objects that combo can be bound do. Similarly, adapters can fill from db in to a datatable or a binding list or you can put data into them manually; it doesn't matter